# Choosing version for Youtube Data API

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing a project where I am supposed to upload and search videos from youtube directly. I started searching and I got to know about using youtube data API. Now there are two versions for it. v3.0 is in experimental phase and v2.0 is old.

I am going to use this for the first time. I am  confused that ...

1. should I use version 2.0 or version 3.0?
2. why should I choose it compared to other?..
3. Is there difference in development complexity?

Please suggest! Thank You to all those who answer.(I am using php/mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally recommend using version 3 for a few reasons.

- Youtube is changing, just like all platforms, and with platform change comes API changes.  Different entities get used, and different methods get created for those entities.  One good example that comes to mind with YouTube is the way you find a channel's uploaded videos.  YouTube switched to using an uploads playlist (treated like any other playlist), and the new API reflects that change.  Version 3 just gets rid of a few old ways of doing things.
- Another major change is the way YouTube wants to handle channels.  Channels are getting more and more oriented around their id's (connected with your G+ account), and less around usernames, and the v3 API's reflect that as well.
- Version 3 will be around a lot longer (because I'm sure v2 will get phased out at some point, just like v1).
- Version 3 is a lot cleaner than version 2 (both documentation and actual endpoints).  This is a pretty easy argument to make, just look at the following two documentation pages. If you can't immediately tell version 3 is a lot easier to navigation, you must be insane!

> Version 3: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/
>
> Version 2: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference

It's a valid argument to say that v3 is still experimental, but I've been using it in production for a couple months and have been pretty happy with it so far.  I wouldn't expect YouTube to be making any huge, sweeping changes at this point.

Comment: I want my users to upload video through my site in my channel only. And after reading all I am using Service Account and I will use direct uploading facility. Is that correct way to do so? (I am little confused because I am doing this for the first time!)


and last question, what is an open SSL? As docs says that we must have an SSL Certificate while sending request to youtube.

And please post any other tutorial links if you know. THank You!